# How to override XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, overriding

I want to override "XMLHttpRequest" this constructor function.

And I just want to alert something when I new a instance, just like this:
(this is not what I actually want to do, just an example)

```
var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //then alert "new a XMLHttpRequest instance!"
```

then I try this:

```
var orig_XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    alert("new a XMLHttpRequest instance!");
    orig_XMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

but when I new an instance,

I get this error at orig_XMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);

```
TypeError: Constructor XMLHttpRequest requires 'new'
```

So, which step I do wrong? How can I override XMLHttpRequest? Or it is impossible?

I also try this:

```
var orig_XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    alert("new a XMLHttpRequest instance!");
    new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(orig_XMLHttpRequest, arguments));
};

var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax_request.open("POST", "./php/register.php", true);
ajax_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function() {.....};
ajax_request.send();
```

but I still got an error :(

```
TypeError: ajax_request.open is not a function
```

Comment: found something very intersting at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

I've been able to modify your second code sample to get something working:

```js
var orig_XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
  document.write("new a XMLHttpRequest instance!");
  return new orig_XMLHttpRequest();
};

var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax_request.open("POST", "./php/register.php", true);
ajax_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax_request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    console.log("request returned status code: " + ajax_request.status);
  }
}
ajax_request.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("request failed: " + e.target.status);
  }

ajax_request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    alert("new a XMLHttpRequest instance!");
    orig_XMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

(EDITED - I made a mistake in my original approach)

Comment: thanks! but i still got an error ~~lol 

TypeError: ajax_request.open is not a function